# How do I install some additional uWSGI plugins?

Tags: plugins, pip, uwsgi

I have installed uWSGI 2.0 - `pip install uwsgi` and I'd like to use syslog plugin. I have by default only python_plugin and python27_plugin. How do I install any additional plugins for uWSGI?

My OS is Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've installed uwsgi from Ubuntu's package and it seems to be splited into many plugins.

I'd stop getting *"unable to find logger syslog"* after adding `--plugin syslog` to the command line.

Comment: For me it worked after adding line "plugins = syslog" in uwsgi ini file.

Answer (score 1):

The syslog plugin is embedded in the binary when you install uWSGI via pip:

https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/buildconf/base.ini#L16

Comment: I read it already, but when I put "log-syslog=true" or "logger=syslog" options to my ini config, uWSGI fails on restart with "unable to find logger syslog" message.